# how to use ajax function to send form without page getting refreshed, what am I missing?Do I have to use rest-framework for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to send my comment form using ajax, right now when user inserts a comment then whole page gets refreshed. I want this to be inserted nicely without page getting refreshed. 
So I tried bunch of things but no luck. since I'm a beginner, I tried to follow many tutorial links;
https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/
https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/django-with-ajax-a-modern-client-server-communication-practise/comment-page-1/#comment-1631

I realize my problem is that I have a hard time manipulating my code in views.py and forms.py 
Thus before doing a client side programming(js and ajax) I need to set my backend(python code) again to be set for the ajax. 
Can someone please help me with this?
I don't know how to set my backend....

```
  <div class="leave comment>
    <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' id='commentForAjax'>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' value='{{ request.get_full_path }}'/>

    {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}
    </form>
    </div>



<div class='reply_comment'>
    <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
    {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

    </form>
    </div>

    <script>
     $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'comment/create/',
        data:{
          post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
          origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
          parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:function(json){
```

I don't know what to do here...I tried it but failing....what is going on here         })

this is my forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "leave your thoughts"})
    )

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(data, files, kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'leave your thoughts', css_class='btn btn-default',))
```

and my views.py

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.is_ajax():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

I'm still very shaky on the idea of using ajax even after reading a tutorial about it...how json comes into play and how I should modify views.py too....can someone please explain how they all group together?and help me getting this done...

```
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: check this jquery plugin [ajax-forms](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) i know this is not the solution, but could help you cleanup a lot of code.

Comment: It'd be great if you show what errors you are encountering. To can trace errors in AJAX requests using your browsers's Network tab in develop tools.

Comment: Have you uploaded your code on GitHub or BitBucket?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro yes my code is on bitbucket, It's also in production

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro sadly no... I'm watching tutorials on rest framework now because I'm getting two answers that use rest framework....can you please help me here?

Comment: I see that you've tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36316159/2932244). And that is correct. You don't need to use REST framework. Simply change the return statement to `return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(new_comment))`. Do a `console.log(json);` inside the `success` function and check if you are getting your comment data. We'll continue this in chat if issue still persist.

Comment: ok thank you, I'll definitely try this

Comment: I still get error, it gives me 500 server error

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro hmm....I switched return jsonresponse like you told me too....

Comment: Let's continue the discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107918).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After completely reviewing your code and discussing with OP in length. I've managed to resolve the OPs issue.

1. After removing `HttpResponseRedirect` I first converted it to `JsonResponse` and made changes accordingly.

   ```
   response_data = {
                        "status":200, "message":"comment_stored", 
                        "parent": True, 
                        "parent_id": parent_comment.id,
                        "comment_count": parent_comment.comment_count()
                    }
   return JsonResponse(response_data)
   ```
2. Next step was to simply perform DOM manipulation to display the data fetched from the response. But turns out this was more complicated than expected. So, to simplify it I simply separated the template into 2 parts - one will be the main part and the other containing the HTML of only the comment.

   Using [`django.template.loader.render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) I generated the required HTML to display the comment and sent with the response as a string in JSON.

   ```
   html = render_to_string('main/child_comment.html', 
                                    {'comment': [new_comment], 
                                     'user': request.user, 
                                     'comment_form':comment_form
                           })
   response_data = { 
                       "status":200, "message":"comment_stored", 
                       "comment":html, 
                       "parent": True, "parent_id": parent_comment.id,
                       "comment_count": parent_comment.comment_count()
                   }
   return JsonResponse(response_data)
   ```
3. Finally, after minor changes (not relevant to the current issue) mainly in the DOM manipulation scripts and in one of the form models, the code worked as expected.

   ```
   $('form').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if ($(this).parents("tr") != 0) {
           parent_id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id").split("_")[1];
           data_str = $(this).serialize() + "&parent_id=" + parent_id;
       } else {
           data_str = $(this).serialize();
       }
       $(this).parents("tr").attr("id").split("_")[1]
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '{% url 'comment_create' %}',
           data: data_str,
           success: function(json) {
               alert(json.message);
               if (json.status == 200) {
                   var comment = json.comment.trim();
                   var user = json.user;
                   if (!json.parent) {
                       $(comment).insertBefore('.table tr:first');
                   } else {
                       $(comment).insertBefore('#comment_' + json.parent_id + ' #child_comment:first');
                       $(".replies").text("답글" + json.comment_count + "개 모두 보기");
                   }
               }

           },
           error: function(response) {
               alert("some error occured. see console for detail");
           }
       });
   });
   ```
4. **BONUS:** There was another minor [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36368734/2932244) which we had faced but I won't discuss it here. I've written a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36376534/2932244) for it.

Comment: hello, with this solution I have two problems. first one is when I try to make a comment then comment again, the second comment gets submitted twice. If I make one more comment third comment gets submitted multiple times as well. Second one is after I make a comment, and try to reply to a different comment, I am unable to unfold text box.....can you please check this issue?  I desperately need some help for this.....

Comment: Hi, not sure if you got my last message...can I expect to see how the commenting/reply box got fixed?and more? please let me know :)

Answer (score 6):

see official document of [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and modify your ajax all like this :

```js
<script>
     $('#commentForAjax' ).submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'comment/create/',  // make sure , you are calling currect url
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(json){              
          alert(json.message); 
          if(json.status==200){
             var comment = json.comment;
             var user = json.user;
             /// set `comment` and `user` using jquery to some element
           }             
        },
        error:function(response){
          alert("some error occured. see console for detail");
        }
      });
     });
```

At backend side you are returning `HttpResponseRedirect()` which will redirect your ajax call to some url(status code=302). I will suggest to return any json response.

For Django 1.7+ add line `from django.http import JsonResponse` to return json response

For pre Django 1.7 use `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")`

Modify this portion of your **views.py** to return **Json response**

```
def comment_create_view(request):
# you are calling this url using post method 
if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
    parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
    post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
    origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    except:
        # you should return from here , if post does not exists
        response = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")

    parent_comment = None
    if parent_id is not None:
        try:
            parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
        except:
            parent_comment = None

        if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
            post = parent_comment.post

    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
        comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        if parent_comment is not None:
            # parent comments exists
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                text=comment_text,
                post = post,
                parent=parent_comment
                )
            response = {"status":200,"message":"comment_stored",
             "user":new_comment.user, 
             "comment":comment_text,
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=origin_path, 
                text=comment_text,
                post = post
                )
            response = {"status":200,"message":"new comment_stored",
             "user":new_comment.user,
             "comment":comment_text,}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
        response = {"status":400,"message":"There was an error with your comment."}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

You don't have to use rest-framework. But if you use rest-framework for this purpose , it will be easy to implement.

Comment: thanks for the solution, do I need to modify forms.py for this? I want to use rest-framework but I've never worked with rest-framework and I just finished my project and minimize any change

Comment: hello with this approach, i have to refresh my page to see the comment

Comment: in your question ` I want this to be inserted nicely without page getting refreshed` , so i thought , you want to just insert without refresh. @mikebraa . Anyways , i will try to edit the answer , so you don't need to refresh , page to see comment

Comment: oh ok, thank you. your answer has been the best to understand and follow...because I don't use rest framework---don't quite know how----anyway yeah if this issue can be fixed it would be awesome

Comment: thanks but I got ValueError at /comment/create/
The view comments.views.comment_create_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: which version of Django , you are using ? @mikebraa

Comment: I'm using django 1.8

Comment: I have added from django.http import JsonResponse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107951/discussion-between-hiren-patel-and-mike-braa).

Comment: yeah with this approach it takes me to comment/create url and give me that message

Answer (score 2):

This is general structure of your comment app. I am assuming you are using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

```
- Comment
    - models.py
    - forms.py
    - views.py
```

- Comment Model **(models.py)**

  ```
  from django.db import models

  class Comment(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
      post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
      parent = models.ForeignKey("self")
      text = models.TextField()
      path = ...
      ...
  ```
- Comment Form **(forms.py)**

  ```
  from django import forms
  from .models import Comment

  class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

      class Meta:
          model = Comment
          fields = ('text', 'post_id', 'parent_id')

      post_id = forms.HiddenInput()
      parent_id = forms.HiddenInput()

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

          self.fields['text'].label = _('Comment')
          self.fields['post_id'].value = self.instance.post.id
          self.fields['parent_id'].value = self.instance.parent.id

          self.helper = FormHelper()
          self.helper.form_show_labels = False
          self.helper.layout = Layout(
              ManageFieldsWrapper(
                  crispy_fields.Field('text')
              ),
              crispy_fields.SubmitField(submit_label='Leave your thoughts')
          )
  ```
- Comment form view and api view **(views.py)**

  ```
  from rest_framework.views import APIView
  from rest_framework.response import Response
  from rest_framework import status
  from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
  from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
  from .forms import CommentForm
  from .models import Comment


  class CommentFormView(CreateView):
      form_class = CommentForm


  class CommentAPISubmitView(APIView):
      def post(self, request, format=None):
          #... Your checks goes here ...
          form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
          if form.is_valid():
              #... Your saving logic here ..
              return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
          else:
              return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

          return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  ```
- Finally client side code **AJAX/JQuery**

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#commentForAjax").submit(function( event ) {
          $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url:'comment/create/',
              data:{
                  post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
                  origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
                  parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
              },
              success: function(response){

              }
          });
          event.preventDefault()
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the solution. but I'm not using rest framework just django regular framework. I really want to solve this for my website, is it possible to achieve this without rest framework? will downloading rest framework effect what's already working?

Comment: plus one for the approach I was thinking of, except I don't use rest framework

Comment: If you don't want to use rest-framework, you can use @HirenPatel solution. You just need to replace API view.

Comment: thanks for the reply Vibhu. yeah I tried it,  this almost works. I can see the data comes through in console but I still have to refresh the page to get the data. I don't know what to do for success function...can you checkout here;http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107918/room-for-jason-estibeiro-and-mike-braa

Comment: I dont get any error in console but I still have to refresh to get the comments

Answer (score 2):

As per your current code It seems like it will always get redirect because after validating the comment form and updating it into database you are returning `HttpResponseRedirect` which is designed to redirect.

I think what you want is to update the comment into database and get a success response.

So to achieve this you need to change the response type, I would suggest return [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and based on the json response you can update the html as well, I am sure returning json response won't cause redirect your html.

Let me know if it's clear to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need to do for preventing page reloading on form submit is calling `event.preventDefault()` in your form `submit` event handler.
@Vibhu provided a very good code example in the answer above. That's exactly what  you need to do on client side. (I provide his code with a single difference, request is sent to 'comment/create-ajax', not to 'comment/create'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#commentForAjax").submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'comment/create-ajax',
        data:{
            post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
            origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
            parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function(response){

        }
    });
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

});

On server side, you may provide one more controller (view in Django terms) which handles `POST /comments/create-ajax`, it should look somehow like this:

```
def handle_comment_creation_via_ajax(request):
    comment_dict = json.loads(request.body)
    # or json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8")) if you use python 3
    comment = CommentModel(**comment_dict) # This will work if comment has no nested models, otherwise, implement static method in your model class which takes dict and returns model instance.
    try:
        comment.save()
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'success':false, 'message': str(e)}, status_code=400)
    return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(instance, fields=[], exclude=[])
```

[JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and [model_to_dict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/_modules/django/forms/models/)

Good luck!

P.S. Note that incoming model must be validated before save

Comment: thank you for the solution, for the answer vibhu provided, he used rest frame work. I've never worked with rest...I thought about ignoring and just follow his example but got stuck because of from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

Comment: for the server side, can you please provide little more detail? do I need to alter forms.py as well?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of example, I would like to show how to achieve this using Django REST Framework and **how much code you DON'T need to change.**

### TL;DR

Installing DRF doesn't break anything. Just add 8 lines of code (without imports), change 2 existing lines and get rid of your entire `comment_create_view`.

For those who are interested in more details, please read further.

#### 1. Install `django-rest-framework` using [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation) guide.

#### 2. Create a `serializers.py` file with the following contents

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'  # or specify the list of fields you want to be present
```

Here you define the class that will serialize (transform a `Comment` model instance to a `json` object) and deserialize (inverse action of transforming a `json` object into a `Comment` instance) your comments.

#### 3. Add the following view to your `views.py`

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
class CommentCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comments.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

**Note:** These 4 lines of code actually substitute your whole `comment_create_view`.

Here you define a generic view designed specifically for creation of objects. `CreateAPIView` will handle only `POST` requests and will use the `CommentSerializer` class to convert objects. A serializer class to Django REST framework is what a form class is to Django - it handles the validation of data and returns a response in form of `json`, or corresponding error messages (also in json) in case your data is not correct.

#### 4. Add the following to your main `urls.py` file

```
url_patterns = [
    ...  # your urls here
    url(r'^api/v1/comments/$', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comments-list')
]
```

Here you register your API view as a route to which you can send requests.

#### 5. Edit your `ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'api/v1/comments/',  // switch to the API view url
    contentType: 'application/json',  // tell ajax to send it as `json` content
    data:{
      post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
      origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
      parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(json){
```

You `POST` to the newly created API endpoint data in form of `json` and your serializer takes it and creates a `Comment` model instance from it that is saved to the database. In case you need some specific behavior while creating a `Comment` (or any other model) instance, you can override the `.create()` method of your `CommentSerializer`. For more details check the [Django REST framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/).

#### 6. Do whatever you need with the newly created `comment`

This part applies to non Django REST framework scenarios as well. Once you've successfully created the `comment`, in your `success` function you will receive it in json form and depending on what you want to do with it, you need to define the desired behavior in this `success` function.

Basically that's it. Please take into account that the example described here is a minimal required code to make it work for you. I've used the out-of-the-box Django REST framework features, but of course it has many more possibilities to make things work. Maybe you'll need to override some default methods, but in the end, because DRF is designed to deal with ajax calls, your code will be shorter and cleaner.

Good luck!

Comment: if you have questions, throw them at me! :)

Comment: oh ok, so basically those four lines in views.py does the same thing as the function in my views.py?

Comment: so I can pretty much remove it and use that? =but I have child comment too

Comment: i want to try this but I'm scared about not understanding views.py, I have parent_comment and child_comment in my views.py and those can be replaced by that??

Comment: @mikebraa can you please post your `Comment` model code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest example of how to implement Ajax forms in conjunction with Django:

You can use Ajax Post to send `JSON` to Django and then handle the arguments as a `dict()`. Here is an example:

In browser (JQuery/JavaScript):

```
    function newModule() {

        var my_data = $("#my_element").val(); // Whatever value you want to be sent.

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'modules' %}",       // Handler as defined in Django URLs. 
            type: "POST",                     // Method.
            dataType: "json",                 // Format as JSON (Default).
            data: {
                path: my_data,                // Dictionary key (JSON). 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
                         '{{ csrf_token }}'   // Unique key.
            },

            success: function (json) {

                // On success do this.

            },

            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                // On failure do this. 

            }

        });
```

In server engine (Python):

```
def handle(request):

    # Post request containing the key.  
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'my_data' in request.POST.keys():

        # Retrieving the value.
        my_data = request.POST['my_data']

    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form is submitting it is not your backend code but your javascript code, you need to prevent the form from submitting, you can try changing this:

```
 <script>
     $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
```

To this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comentForAjax").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do whatever you need to do, like serializing the form and post with $.ajax
    });
  });
```

So make sure you are binding the submit event right after the document loads so the browser knows that the form should not be submitted, and then you just make your ajax call and do whatever you need with the returned serialized data from the server.

Again, if the form is posting, it doesn't have anything to do with the backend code.

**Note:**  For jquery selectors, if you need to select something by id you use the `#element` hash sign and if you want to target class selectors then you use the dot notation `.elements`. Also note that you can in theory select just one element by ID (given that you don't duplicate the ID for other elements) but classes are usually used to span several elements that share the same attributes.

Answer (score -1):

In your javascript, you call for the class .commentForAjax.
You should call the ID:

```
$(document).on('submit','#commentForAjax', function(e){
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps.
R

Answer (score -1):

In your form tag below

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' id='commentForAjax'>{% csrf_token %}
```

You don't need to define action or method. You handle them via ajax. So delete them and you form won't try to execute that action.And hopefully it will solve your refresh page issue.Also change your on submit line `'.commentForAjax'` into `'#commentForAjax'` since it is not a class but id.

Comment: fixing this doesn't work, yeah I caught that... that was just a typo

Answer (score -1):

$(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

// Put

e.stopPropagation();

Comment: before this I have a problem in my views.py,,,,i need to set is_ajax()