# when "a" gets posted, an image "b" gets posted as well. how do I make an image "c" to get posted with "a" after "a" got posted with an image"b"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

sorry if title is very confusing. On my web, when user posts url then a default image I set gets posted along with the url. so if a lot user posts url, then same default image gets displayed on my web multiple times. Because, it's boring I want to mix up images. I want to have number of images, and each image to get displayed one after one when user posts url.

```
import json
from goose import Goose

DEFAULT = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1417028441456-f283323fe2d6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=c48033d726ec5227264b186342c0a8e5'
DEFAULT1 = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452447224378-04c089d77aa4?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1550'
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    try:
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return DEFAULT 

        else:
            if article.top_image.src is None:
              return DEFAULT1
            else:
                resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
                return article.top_image.src
    except ParseError:
        if can_handle():
                handle_exception()
            else:
                print("couldn't handle exception: url={0}".format(url))
                raise
```

Instead of just one DEFAULT image, I want there to be more images and that images to be used. how do I do that?

Comment: Define an array of images and pick a random element?

Comment: @serg that's great idea thank you, so it's like myList=[img1,img2] then return (random generator code...) do you know any random generator code?

Comment: `random.choice(myList)`?

Comment: @Selcuk thank you selduck, can you please help me with this;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217678/how-to-use-ajax-function-to-send-form-without-page-getting-refreshed-what-am-i I'm gonna add bounty on this, it has been bugging me for a week now....every tutorial on ajax, form has their own ways I'm so confused now