# ajax failing, I'm not using HttpResponseRedirect but it takes me to different url and show some javascript console message

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm not sure why it's returning it like this;https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqqYZ.jpg
I don't have HttpResponseRedirect for this but it takes me to different url. What I'm trying to do is to let users insert comment without page getting refreshed. I don't get any errors in console, but it's just not working which I don't understand.

In my html

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' id="commentForAjax" class='form-comment'>{% csrf_token %}

<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='origin_path' value='{{ request.get_full_path }}'/>

{% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}
</form>

<script>
     $('#commentForAjax' ).submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/comment/create/',  // make sure , you are calling currect url
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(json){              
          alert(json.message); 
          if(json.status==200){
             var comment = json.comment;
             var user = json.user;
             /// set `comment` and `user` using jquery to some element
             var comment_content = '<div class="row">\
                      <div class="col-sm-1">\
                   <a href="' + user + '"><img src="#" height='48' width='48' /></a>\
                      </div>\
                      <div class="col-sm-11">\
                        <div class="row">\
                          <div class="col-sm-12">\
                            <p> <a href="{#" style="padding:5px;">{{ comment.user.user }}</a>| <small>1 </small></p>\
                          </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="row">\
                  <span style="margin:5px; word-break: break-all;">\
                    ' + comment + '\
                </span>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </div>';

              $(comment_content).insertAfter('.table .row');
           }  

        },
        error:function(response){
          alert("some error occured. see console for detail");
        }
      });
     });
</script>
```

and in my views.py

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            response_dat = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)


        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )

                response_data = {"status":200,"message":"comment_stored",
                    "user":new_comment.user.user, 
                    "comment":comment_text,
                 }
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                response_data = {"status":200,"message":"new comment_stored",
                #"user":new_comment.user,
                "comment":comment_text,}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)

        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            response_data = {"status":400,"message":"There was an error with your comment."}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

my url

```
#Comments
urlpatterns += patterns('comments.views',
    url(r'^comment/create/$', 'comment_create_view', name='comment_create'),
)
```

Comment: put `console.log("something") in success function. And check your browsers console. tick preserve log checkbox in console. and see , if you are going into success function or not

Comment: try removing **action** attribute of Django form @mikebraa

Comment: @Hirenpatel then comment doesn't get saved

Comment: @Hirenpatel  it's going in I think console shows 200 with comment being saved

Comment: redirect problem is strill there ?

Comment: yeap...which is why it's driving me crazy

Comment: can you share your full html code ?

Comment: yeah sure,,,really hope to fix this;http://dpaste.com/2FCJNXK

Comment: you should accept an answer here . http://stackoverflow.com/a/36316159/3553279

Comment: @Hirenpatel sure I'll accept that, I tried it but didn't work tho...from there few things got modified that led me to this

Comment: You most likely have js error somewhere so it fails to stop the form from sending POST request to action url. So it's not an ajax that is sending the request, it's the form itself. As suggested, try enabling preserving console logs and look for js errors.

Comment: @serg ok so delete my success function and use console logs there instead?

Comment: Just open your browsers console and look for js errors. Because the page gets redirected and the console is cleared on redirects, you need to enable persistent logs first (developer tools setting).

Comment: In the question, you have mentioned `javascript console erros` . can you show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I reviewed the complete code and discussed with OP on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107918). Turns out there was **another** event listener (not mentioned in the question) further down in the code which basically submits the form.

Hence, the issue still didn't resolve once the `action` attribute was removed from the form. Cause then the form would simply submit a POST request with `action=""`. And hence the page would simply reload.

Comment: Hello....hopefully you didn't forget about me ;) can you please help me with the issue I'm having??

Comment: @mikebraa - Check the chat.